# ASP.NET MVC application - CSS works in development - not in production

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that I just updated. The CSS (uses Bootstrap) was fine until I moved in the latest update. The CSS works fine in development also. I can't figure out what has changed.

When I view the source, the includes for the CSS are as follows...

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<meta name="x-stylesheet-fallback-test" content="" class="sr-only" /><script>!function(a,b,c,d){var e,f=document,g=f.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),h=g[g.length-1].previousElementSibling,i=f.defaultView&&f.defaultView.getComputedStyle?f.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h):h.currentStyle;if(i&&i[a]!==b)for(e=0;e<c.length;e++)f.write('<link href="'+c[e]+'" '+d+"/>")}("position","absolute",["\/lib\/bootstrap\/dist\/css\/bootstrap.min.css"], "rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 ");</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.min.css?v=o58rbQrBnue0iUvODYSom2NdDcN5ac2Wx9aBfJjV0VI" />
```

I'm not sure what needs to be corrected here. I have set the environment from Development to Release before building.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bob

P.S. - Here is the updated markup now that I have restored the prior version.

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/FontAwesome/all.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Here is the source code for the _Layout.cshtml view and the commented out section is what I had tried before. Neither of these seems to allow the CSS (shown above in most recent Html markup) to be rendered.

```
    <environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/FontAwesome/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery-ui.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/FontAwesome/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />*@
</environment>
```

Comment: What specifically is wrong?

Comment: The bootstrap CSS is not recognized so the formatting, particularly of the header area in the _Layout.cshtml view. It also does not seem to be recognizing any of the FontAwesome icons used in some views.

Comment: Did you check the network requests in the browser's development tools? Did you confirm that all the necessary resource files are being retrieved without errors?

Comment: I did not, but given that this was a production server, I restored the previous version to get it working again. After that, I noticed that the html markup for the style sheets looks different. I'll post a response with the updated markup.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to resolve this CSS issue by removing the conditional  variables. Rather than conditionally stating the CSS #includes, I just explicitly stated them. Now, in the production version the CSS is recognized.

Here is how the code looks now.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/FontAwesome/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery-ui.css" />
```